# fluentmigrator Guid MySQL type

Tags: mysql, fluent-migrator

Currently when a column is set to be Guid (using AsGuid()) it creates it as a VARCHAR(40). Is there a reason for this? Instead can it be updated to use CHAR(36)?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this with a workaround by creating an extension method:

```
public static IAlterTableColumnOptionOrAddColumnOrAlterColumnSyntax AsCustomGuid(this IAlterTableColumnAsTypeSyntax migration)
{
        return migration.AsCustom("CHAR(36)");
}
```

So instead of using AsGuid(), I can use AsCustomGuid().